# JavaScript создать объект из массива

Tags: javascript

Имеется такой массив:

```
const arr = [
  CaretDown,
  CaretUp,
  FileDownload,
  FileUpload
]
```

Из этого массива я хочу получить такой объект:

```
const obj = {
      CaretDown,
      CaretUp,
      FileDownload,
      FileUpload
}
```

[image: Как выглядит console.log(obj)]
Подскажите как это можно сделать?

Comment: никак. такой объект невалиден

Comment: вот если ключи будут числовыми а значения строковыми - тогда другое дело

Comment: либо приведенные значения будут ключами, а значением что-то еще, а-ля null

Comment: console.log(obj) говорит об обратном. Добавил скрин.

Comment: тут ключ-значение. ключ - имя, значение - функция

Comment: А то, что вы привели в коде, а не на скринах - невалидно

Comment: `obj = {CaretDown:CaretDown}` и так далее.

Comment: Добавьте больше деталей (например зачем? что вы хотите получить в результате или как использовать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это надо?

```js
let CaretDown = () => { console.log(1); };
let CaretUp = () => { console.log(2); };
let FileDownload = () => { console.log(3); };
let FileUpload = () => { console.log(4); };

const obj = {
      CaretDown,
      CaretUp,
      FileDownload,
      FileUpload
}


obj.CaretDown();
obj.CaretUp();
obj.FileDownload();
obj.FileUpload();
```

---

Из массива в объект:

```js
let CaretDown = () => { console.log(1); };
let CaretUp = () => { console.log(2); };
let FileDownload = () => { console.log(3); };
let FileUpload = () => { console.log(4); };

const arr = [CaretDown, CaretUp, FileDownload, FileUpload];
let obj = {};

arr.forEach(el => {
  obj[el.name] = el;
});

obj.CaretDown();
obj.CaretUp();
obj.FileDownload();
obj.FileUpload();
```

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо!